# Can I improve this method of concatenation of strings?

Tags: java, string, performance, optimization, stringbuilder

Here is the method :

```
    private String getCommentaireReprise(TableRow row) {

    return "Produit : " + getProduit(row) +
            "\n Dossier fournisseur : " + getDossierFournisseur(row) +
            "\n Dossier Truffaut : " + getDossierTruffaut(row) +
            "\n Ref loueur : " + getRefLoueur(row) +
            "\n Merchandising : " + getMerchandising(row) +
            "\n Libelle court : " + getLibelleCourt(row) +
            "\n Libelle SAP : " + getLibelleSap(row) +
            "\n Nombres Images 360 : " + getNombreImages(row) +
            "\n Uploadé par : " + getUploadePar(row) +
            "\n Crédit photo : " + getCreditPhoto(row);
}
```

Is is better to use a StringBuilder rather than this ? or to use JSONObject and to cast it at the end with .toString() ?

Comment: IIRC, the compiler will transform this into a `StringBuilder` call chain. --- On a side note: I would recommend to use `System.lineSeparator()` instead of `"\n"`.

Comment: Better still, use a `PrintWriter` with `StringWriter` or use `String.format`. Also consider not using string literals and internationalization

Comment: @Turing85  `StringBuilder` is not used anymore since Java 9...  see [JEP 280](https://openjdk.org/jeps/280) (or [`StringConcatFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.html))

Comment: for readability, I would eventually use Text Block and `formatted()` (or similar methods, see [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html))

Answer (score 1):

The posted code actually performs better than code you'd manually write, even with a string builder, for any version of Java >= 9 -- due to the use of [`StringConcatFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.html).  `StringConcatFactory` can generate code better than you could *possibly* handwrite, since it can do tricks like directly writing into the final byte array used in the `String` instead of the copy that even `StringBuilder` has to do.

(Since you have tagged this question "performance" and "optimization," I assume pure speed is your priority.  If it's about what's "better" in general, that would be an opinion-based question and would not be appropriate for StackOverflow as a result.)